# Asp.net how to make a 2 level commenting system

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am using asp.net and MySQL and I want to make a 2 level commenting system. Here is the table design:

- Id(Primary key) SMALLINT
- IsApproved BOOL
- PageId TINYINT
- UserName VARCHAR(255)
- Comment TEXT
- Date TIMESTAMP
- ReplyTo SMALLINT
- IpAddress INT
- UserAgent VARCHAR(255)

Is there an sql statement that I can use to organize the comments or would it have to be server side. An example of a 2 level commenting system.

- Comment 1

  - Reply to Comment 1
  - Reply to Comment 1
- Comment 2
- Comment 3

Thanks

Comment: By "2 level commenting system", I'm assuming you mean a reply can have sub reply's, but no deeper than that?

Comment: A comment can have multiple replys but a reply can not have another reply.

Comment: Please make some effort into researching or trying something out and then ask for parts you don't understand. This questions is not constructive in it's current shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would advise against using smallint as primary key.  Just use int.  Smallint will run out of space after 32,767 rows.

For DateTime, you want to use the actual type DateTime, not TimeStamp, and set the default value to GetDate()

To get "root" comments, just filter by ReplyTo is Null, then order by DateTime.

Comment: Oh its part of a small project, it wont be available to the internet.

Comment: Even still, I would use int.  Small int is non standard, and will actually require more work on the front end. Trust me, just use int, it won't add any overhead at all.

Comment: Ok thanks, I already have the root comment thing working. How would I go with organizing the comments.

Comment: Do you know to organize the replys?